# Why does updating one MFC CStatic control causes the dialog to be erased?

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm writing a dialog that plays video on a dialog frame by frame, and displays some status info around it. The dialog resource contains just a few CStatic controls that have bitmaps drawn on them.

The loop looks like this

```
DWORD  milliPerFrame = std::lround(1000.0 / videoFile.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS));

unsigned int videoFrameCount = (unsigned int)videoFile.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT),
    videoFrameWidth  = (unsigned int)videoFile.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH),
    videoFrameHeight = (unsigned int)videoFile.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);

uint64_t startTime, endTime;

CVideoDlg* canvas = new CVideoDlg();
canvas->Create(IDD_VIDEO_DIALOG, this);
canvas->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);

CRect dialogSize = canvas->getDrawingRect();

int winFrameWidth  = dialogSize.right - dialogSize.left,
    winFrameHeight = dialogSize.bottom - dialogSize.top;

cv::Mat vFrame, dFrame;

for (unsigned frameNo = 1; frameNo <= videoFrameCount; frameNo++)
{
    startTime = getCurrTime();

    videoFile.read(vFrame);
    cv::resize(vFrame, dFrame, cv::Size(winFrameWidth, winFrameHeight));

    canvas->setFrame(dFrame);

    bool status = (frameNo % 2 == 0);

    canvas->setStitchingStatus(status);

    endTime = getCurrTime();

    Sleep(std::max(0, (int)(milliPerFrame - (endTime - startTime))));
}
```

The real code calls a routine that returns a status, which I've commented out for debug purposes.

The CVideoDlg has an OnInitDialog routine which calls ModifyStyle(0xF, SS_BITMAP, 0) for each of the CStatic controls, the two set methods, and getDrawingRect.

The stitching status is simple

```
void CVideoDlg::setStitchingStatus(bool status)
{
    m_Stitching.ShowWindow(status ? SW_SHOW : SW_HIDE);
}
```

setFrame is a rather long routine, that draws the frame on another CStatic using StretchDIBits.

Problem is, stepping through with the debug I can see each CStatic drawn correctly, but causing the other one to be erased.

Why is that happening, and how can I fix it?

Edit: the top right rectangle is the stitching status CStaticm, the large one is the frame.

[image]

Edit: I've overridden the dialog's PreTranslateMessage method and put a break on it to see what messages it gets that might erase it's background. Nothing.

I've added a call to the dialog's RedrawWindow, and all the bitmaps correctly appear, but I still wonder why is it deleted in the first place.

Comment: Please post an image of your dialog and clearly show the position and size of each of the static controls.

Comment: @Michael Walz - I've edited the original post to add the dialog.

The top right rectangle is the stitching status CStaticm, the large one is the frame.

Comment: There are _two_ rectangles on the top and they are on the _left_ side.

Comment: Yes, both are on the left side, but of those two one is one the left and one is on the right.

Comment: For debugging purposes put the two statics at some significant distance and check what happens.

Comment: I've enlarged the dialog and moved the frame CStatic away about as far as it is tall, and moved the top two CStatic controls away from each other.

Stepping with the debugger, the frame CStatic is drawn, and when I step to change the stitching CStatic either way, the dialog is completely erased. Next round through, the video frame is drawn, and the whole dialog is wiped at the same point, repeating until the video runs out.

Comment: Try to remove the `ModifyStyle(0xF, SS_BITMAP, 0) ` it is most likely related to that some way.

Comment: Nope, commenting those out didn't change anything.

Comment: Do any of your controls have `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT`?

Comment: No. Actually, the constant is nowhere to be found in the whole project.

Comment: Please produce a [mcve]. There's nothing we can do without reproducing the issue.